# Azure - Subscription End Date for Free Products for 12 Months and Costs appearing for free products also

Tags: web-hosting, free, azure, cost

I have signed up on Azure portal and received $200 credit for first 30 days and some free products for 12 months, my free subscription has ended after 30 days and I upgraded to Pay as you go subscription, now as said by Azure that even after 30 days of free subscription, I have access to some free products for 12 months.

> I want to know when will my 12 months period expire as I don't
>   remember my sign up date.

and the other thing I want to know is that even when I am trying to use a product (mentioned for free for 12 months), it is showing me its prices. 
Like as said in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/ here, 
I have

> Windows Virtual Machines (B1S VM) COMPUTE for 750 hours free for first 12 months

but even when I am trying to use it, it is showing me its monthly cost.